# GUI issue with the buttons no action happens

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with this code the buttons of the gridPanel won't get clicked.

Note: BKJpanel and BK1Jpanel are classes I made that extend JPanel to edit the icons painting.

CustomJButton is also a class i made that extends JButton for the same reason and it takes the ActionListener as a parameter for it's constructor when initialized then the addActionListenener is added to the constructor to take the passed ActionListenener.

Another note: Board is a class of a game engine I made. It doesn't have anything to do with the problem I think :D

```
public class BoardGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

    JPanel WholePanels;
    BKJpanel gridPanel;
    BK1Jpanel EastPanel;
    JPanel NorthPanel;
    CustomJButton[][] btn;
    Board santorini;

    static CustomJButton newGame;
    static Board rePlay;
    static JLabel labe3;
    static JLabel labe4;

    public BoardGUI(Board santorini) {
        super();
        setTitle("SANTORINI");
        setSize(1366, 766);
        setLocation(0, 0);
        this.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.santorini = santorini;
        rePlay = santorini;

        InitBoardPanels();
        BoardConfig();
        setNewIcons();

        WindowDestroyer wd = new WindowDestroyer();
        addWindowListener(wd);
    }

public void InitGridButtons() {
        btn = new CustomJButton[5][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < btn[i].length; j++) {
                btn[i][j] = new CustomJButton(null, 1.5f, "Ready", this);
                gridPanel.add(btn[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if (arg0.getSource() == newGame) {
            this.santorini = rePlay;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    if ((arg0.getSource() == btn[i][j])) {
                        Logic(i, j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the InitGridButtons method is called in the BoardConfig method

Comment: Your question is about action listener, but I don't see an action listeners anywhere, beside the class definition, in which case I see no actionPerformed method, of the listener being added to anything. Please provide the _relevant_ code to your question. And ask a specific question. _What_ doesn't happen?

Comment: i said up there that the CustomJButton takes the listener as a parameter i.e no addActionListener is needed and the actionPerformed method i didn't use it i used mouseClicked method

Comment: So where do you add the mouse listener to anything? Consider posting a running example. You have not provided enough information or even a clear enought description for us to help you